# java NCache - GeneralFailureException: No server is available to process the request

Tags: java, ncache

I use NCache java API for connecting to NCache server but it throws an exception:
     **com.alachisoft.ncache.runtime.exceptions.GeneralFailureException: No server is available to process the request.**

I also tried some suggestion from [this site](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help/no-server.html)
but cannot solve the problem.
Here are the java codes.

```
String cacheId = "mycache";
try {
    cache = NCache.initializeCache(cacheId);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "NCacheConnection()", ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me a few things ? Can you show me your client.ncconf and can you check what IP are you using. You can see it inside cache.ncconf

Comment: Also what version of NCache ?

Comment: I'm using enterprise 4.0.0.
I tried to connect to a cache with id "mycache" and IP 169.254.80.80.

Comment: Here is  part of my client.ncconf:
  <configuration>
    <ncache-server connection-retries="5" retry-connection-delay="0" retry-interval="1" client-request-timeout="90" connection-timeout="5" port="9800"/>
    <cache id="mycache" client-cache-id="" client-cache-syncmode="optimistic" default-readthru-provider="" default-writethru-provider="" load-balance="True" enable-client-logs="False" log-level="error">
      <server name="169.254.80.80"/>
    </cache>
  </configuration>

Comment: Is your `IP` `169.254.80.80` correct? Can you get that confirmed from `Alachisoft.NCache.Service.exe.config` in your installation folder `/bin/service`. The tag you should be looking for is `<add key="NCacheServer.BindToClientServerIP" value="20.200.20.126"/>`

Comment: @Basit Yess, the IP is correct. I also change the port in client.ncconf to 8250 to match the port in Alachisoft.NCache.Service.exe.
    <add key="NCacheServer.ManagementPort" value="8250"/>
    I started the cache by typing "startcache mycache /s 169.254.80.80" and it is started successfully but I cannot connect to the cache via the API.

Comment: Try putting this underneath configuration in your client.ncconf
`<ncache-client bind-ip-address="ipaddress" />`

Comment: It is the same.